# Extract matrix from resulting multiprocessing object

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

The following code generates a matrix of 0,1 values:

```
def func(num):
    X = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 16) for _ in range(num)]
    X = list(set(X))
    X = [('{0:0' + str(16) + 'b}').format(x) for x in X]
    X = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X], dtype=np.int8)
    return X

mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
X = mlp.map(func, [num])
print X
mlp.close()
mlp.join()
```

The matrix `X` has the following output:

```
[array([[1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)]
```

But I just want:

```
[[1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
..., 
[1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]]
```

How to do so?

Comment: Can you share the definition of func and num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of func returns a numpy array, not a native python list.  If you want to get a native Python list from this function you can use the [tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method on the numpy array object.  If there any reason why func() needs to return a numpy array instead of a native Python list?

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import random

def func(num):
    X = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 16) for _ in range(num)]
    X = list(set(X))
    X = [('{0:0' + str(16) + 'b}').format(x) for x in X]
    X = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X], dtype=np.int8)
    return X

mlp = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
X = mlp.map(func, [10])
mlp.close()
mlp.join()

data = X[0].tolist()

print(data)
```